# Programming ARM in C from scratch

Tags: c, arm, cpu-registers, hal

I have a LPC3141 developers kit from Embeded artists and i have sucessfully created free IDE based on eclipse that can sucesfully compile for ARM. I tested my IDE using included blinker example. I have a startup code and a linker script which work and i will use them from now on.

Now i would like to learn how to start my own blinker program from nothing. What do i have to program first? Is it GPIO registers, timer registers, uart registers,... ??? What is the very first thing? Is the thing i need to write in fact a HAL? I allready ordered this [book](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/C-Programming-for-Embedded-Microcontrollers-Warwick-Smith/9780905705804), what do you think?

Thank you.

Regards Ziga

Comment: If you have the code, can't you examine it to see what you need to write?

Answer (score 2):

These pages might be useful, same family, different chips.

http://lpcstuff.blogspot.com/2008/09/lpc-2148-blinker-1.html

http://lpcstuff.blogspot.com/2010/08/nxp-mbed-aint-so-bad-after-all.html

You wont need timers or interrupts or anything like that to get started.  have a C loop count for a (long) while then change the state of the gpio.   You will need to configure the gpio as an output.  And careful not to have the C compiler optimize out your delay loop.  Later you can get into polling the timer, then after that interrupts if you feel you really need to.

Comment: I guess those were asm only examples, this one is a different arm, but shows the asm to C connection, http://sam7stuff.blogspot.com/ click on my name/profile and see a number of similar sites, mostly about blinking the led on various arm micros, asm and C.

Answer (score 0):

it is **really easy** to get started with arm microcontrollers. all you need to do is reading the **datasheet and user manual** of your microcontroller. you can find all documentation about peripherals and registers in the user manual

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10362.pdf

for example, this code is for lpc2148 ():

```
#include <lpc214x.h> // this header file is provided by nxp and contains all register addresses

/* delay function is using only for loop to generate delay. 
For accurate timing, use a hardware timer/counter (systick timer is recommended (because it is so easy and configurable via cmsis functions that are provided by ARM)) */
void delay_ms(unsigned int count)
{
  unsigned int j=0,i=0;
  for(j=0;j<count;j++)
  {
    for(i=0;i<3000;i++)
        asm("nop");
  }
}

/* main function */
int main() 
{
    PINSEL2 = 0x000000;  //Configure the P1 Pins for GPIO;
    IODIR1 = 0xffffffff; //Configure the P1 pins as OUTPUT;

    while(1)
    {
       IOSET1 = 0xffffffff;     // Make all the Port pins as high  
       delay_ms(1000);

       IOCLR1 = 0xffffffff;     // Make all the Port pins as low  
       delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```